# Prove that sum of 2 double factorials equals to a factorial only on limited solutions

Tags: number-theory, factorial

Suppose a! = b!! + c!!, prove that a + b + c < 2022

I can only prove that both b, c are odd numbers.

I wrote a program to search for solutions, which only gives (2,1,1), (3,3,3) and (5,5,7). But I can't prove that they are the only solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove we know all solutions. Here is an outline of a
proof strategy. Since I shall have not the time to write down the details in the near future, I hope the steps indicated are sufficiently clear so as their proofs present no difficulties.

Below we suppose $1\le b\le c$ and $bc$ odd.

**Fact 1.**  The only solutions with $b=c$ are $(a,b,c)=(2,1,1), (3,3,3)$.

**Fact 2.**  The only solution with $b=1$ is $(a,b,c)=(2,1,1)$.

From now on we may suppose $3\le b<c$. For each such solution, we shall
put $R=b!!+c!!$.

**Fact 3.** There exist positive integers  $s$, $t$ such that  $\{b,c\} = \{8s\pm 1, 8t+5\} $. In particular, $b$, $c\in \{5, 7, 9, 13, 15, 17,21, 23, 25, 29, \ldots\}$.

**Fact 4.** $b=5$ only for $(a,b,c)=(5,5,7)$.

**Fact 5.** No solution exists with $7\le b<53$

**Fact 6.** (Legendre's formula)
$$v_p(x!)= \lfloor \frac{x}{p} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{x}{p^2} \rfloor +\lfloor \frac{x}{p^3} \rfloor + \cdots$$

**Standing hypotheses**
$53\le b<c, \quad 34 \le a< c . $

For an integer $x\ge 2$, let $q(x)$ denote the largest prime which is less than or equal to $x$.

**Fact 7.** (Nagura's analogue of Bertrand's postulate)
There exists a prime between $x$ and $1.2x$ for any $x\ge 25$.

J. Nagura,  On the interval containing at least one prime number,
*Proc.  Japan Acad., Ser. A* **28**, no. 4   (1952), 177--181.
doi:10.3792/pja/1195570997.

**Fact 8.** $q(a)=q(b)$.

**Fact 9.** $5b+1 \le 6a$

**Fact 10.**  $c-b\ge 6$,  $v_3(b!! +c!!)=v_3(b!!)$.

**Fact 10.** $v_3(a!)>v_3(b!!)$.

From the last two facts one concludes that the equation has no solution satisfying **Standing hypotheses**.